# End line '\n' issue in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I could see a space popping up by default if I use '\n' in python 3x. Could someone please help me in removing it?

Appreciate your help in advance!

**sample code:**

```
a='How are you?'
print("Hello, World.\n",a)
```

**Output**

```
Hello, World.
 How are you?
```

**Explanation**

The second line of the output starts with a space. Why is this happening?

Comment: Why is python-2.7 tagged?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As stated in the Python3 documentation, the [print()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function does as follows:

> Print objects to the text stream file, separated by sep and followed by end. sep, >end, file and flush, if present, must be given as keyword arguments.

Therefore, there's a number of ways to solve your issue:
1. Use the *sep* keyword argument, removing the default space separator.

```
a='How are you?'
print("Hello, World.\n", a, sep='')
```

2. Use the .format() function.

```
a='How are you?'
print("Hello, World.\n{}".format(a))
```

3. Use two print statements.

```
a='How are you?'
print("Hello, World.")
print(a)
```

All of these options will output:

```
Hello, World.
How are you?
```

Although all three are valid implementations, I'd personally choose option two as I feel it's a cleaner and more logical solution.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

By consulting the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function

You can see that in Python3 the `print` function uses a space separator to print the arguments passed to it.

To change this behavior you can use `print` as:

```
print("Hello, World.\n", a, sep="")
```

Answer (score 1):

The comma adds in the space. There is a difference in-between:

```
print(a, b)
```

and

```
print(a+b)
```

Cheers,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

`print`separates its arguments by spaces. You may use two prints and omit the explicit newline `\n`:

```
print("Hello, World.")
print(a)
```

or you concatenate the strings:

```
print("Hello, World.\n" + a)
```

or you use a format

```
print("Hello, World.\n%s" % a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Comma is creating space replce it as

```
a='How are you?'
print("Hello, World.\n"+a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The comma is causing the space. Use the `+` sign to concatenate like this:

```
a='How are you?'
print("Hello, World.\n" + a)
```

outputs:

```
Hello, World.
How are you?
```

Comment: Actually it's not the comma, but the default value of the `sep` keyword argument.

Comment: @Szabolcs True, it is because the comma is making the string and `a` to be two different entities which are then concatenated by print. While when using the `+` operator the two strings are already concatenated before print fires. Or yes, you could set the default value of the separator to `""` and still use commas like you pointed out above.